# How to handle Site Guard of Drupal website in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drupal-7

The dev website on Drupal has Site Guard. I am trying to automate the website using Selenium but each time it is asking for Site Guard credentials to be entered. I treated it as regular alert but it seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Siteguard is a software or a service, anyways I think that what you are trying to do is not in the Drupal side, if the development site has some kind of protection, then you must configure that protection, to let you Selenium test to do its work... What about configure Siteguard to not bother a certain IP? Or maybe some cookie?

Hope that helps.